# Appending keys to a hash in an each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I am walking through a rails Hash tutorial and got stuck on how to manipulate hashes in a loop. I have got a hash called `products`:

```
products = Product.where(category: 'electronics', price: 10000).pluck_to_hash(:id)
# => [{:id=>23}, {:id=>12}, {:id=>108}]
```

and my aim is to iterate through it like this:

```
products.each do |p|
  @store = Store.where(product: p[:id], country: gb).pluck_to_hash(:store_code, :manager_name)
end
```

and store all 6 store results in the `@store` instance variable so I can pass it to view.

Using `=` only ends up with one
store and not all 6 stores I'm trying to get. `<<` is only for arrays.

I also tried

```
@store.merge!(Store.where(product: p[:id], country: gb).pluck_to_hash(:store_code, :manager_name))
```

and got:

> undefined method `merge!' for nil:NilClass

Then I declared an empty Hash before the loop:

```
@store = {}
```

and that gave:

> no implicit conversion of Array into Hash

Any guidance on how to iteratively store those keys in `@store` varaible will be greatly appreciated.

Please note that this question isn't about model associations; it's specific to Hash manipulations.

Comment: Why is `@store` a Hash and not an Array? To store something in a Hash you need to give it a key (e.g. `hash["foo"] = 123`). What do you intend to use as the keys in the `@store` Hash?

Comment: Why do you think a hash is the answer here? This is clear cut [X & Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you are trying to paint the house with shovel and wondering if the length of the handle is the problem.

Comment: @store is a Hash because pluck_to_hash returns a Hash - https://github.com/girishso/pluck_to_hash

Comment: @max, hopefully my comment regarding the pluck_to_hash gem addresses your question.

Comment: So why don't you initialize ``@store`` as an array and use ``<<`` instead of ``=``. Your ``@store`` array will then contain the hashes inside another array (which you can flatten if you like). You then simply iterate over your ``@store`` in your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why it does not work:

On each iteration of the loop you are replacing the variable `@store` with another `ActiveRecord::ProxyCollection`.

```
products.each do |p|
  @store = Store.where(product: p[:id], country: gb).pluck_to_hash(:store_code, :manager_name)
end
```

While you could do it like so:

```
products.each do |p|
  @store[p[:id]] = Store.where(product: p[:id], country: gb).pluck_to_hash(:store_code, :manager_name)
end
```

However this is just the wrong way to solve the problem from the start.

Hashes are meant to store key - value data where a value corresponds to a known key. Ruby is not like PHP which completely mixes up arrays and dictionary like "objects" (associative arrays).

Arrays are like stacks where the order matters, hashes are key value. And what you want here is not a hash.

Instead you would solve it like so:

```
products = Product.where(category: 'electronics', price: 10000).pluck(:id)
# this gives us an array of ids
@stores = Store.where(product: products, country: gb)
```

But you probally should be setting up proper relations here and using `.joins` with a condition on the joined table.

```
@stores = Store.joins(:product)
               .where(product: { category: 'electronics', price: 10000 }, country: gb)
```

This is much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @max. That was very educative.